# How do I import data from javascript into a mongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, mongodb

I am attempting to use a geolocation script that collects the location of the user. I'll also eventually add a geocoder but that can wait. This is the script:

```
<script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }

    </script>
```

My goal is to take the data that was collected about the user, and store it into a database using mongoDB where *I* can see it. I am new to javascript but I know how to use mongoDB fairly well. Can anybody help me?

Comment: As I understand from your comments, you know Nodejs and Mongo (back-end environment), and you also know a bit of front-end (browser) Javascript, but you don't know how to link them together. The answer is : Ajax calls :) Call your server from the browser and pass it your data. Then use the server to store data in Mongo.

Comment: Could you give anything that might show me what to do? Like I kinda said, my javascript/node knowledge is minimal compared to what I know of mongo.

Comment: Look up "ajax call", either in pure JS or with the help of jQuery. There are quadrillions of tutorials everywhere. For Node, I recommend using the Mongoose module to work with Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do it without backend language like node js or php or something else. You need to create api  in backend language and then you can use frontend js to hit that api and get and store results.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in answer above by @DHRUV GUPTA you need a backend and that is for both security as connecting to the db shouldnt be from the browser side and also to be able to use packages like [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). It is pretty similar in format to the mongoshell and shouldn't take too long to get used

Comment: I think I'm just unsure what to use as a 'backend'. I'm using the HTML5 geolocation API, but I'm familiar with using both node.js and PHP. I just don't know what I'd write for those.

Comment: nodejs with express framework is a pretty fast and easy option imo